# Getting a sqlite exception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a beginner in SQLite and getting this exception in the highlighted line-
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: VocabDatabase (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Word, Meaning FROM VocabDatabase WHERE _id = ?

My MainActivity code -

```
try {
        **strong textCursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.DB_name, new String[]{"Word", "Meaning"},
                "_id = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(0)}, null, null, null);**
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String word = cursor.getString(0);
            String meaning = cursor.getString(0);
            TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            tv1.setText(word);
            tv2.setText(meaning);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't access the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

SQLite Helper -

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{   db.execSQL("create table Vocabwords (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Word text, Meaning text)");
insertNewEntry(db, "Diabolic","Evil");
insertNewEntry(db,"Concede","Agree to an argument after declaring it incorrect in past");
}
```

Comment: But what unclear is in `no such table: VocabDatabase` message?

Answer (score 0):

**VocabDatabase** is a **database** name, but in `SELECT` clause, you need a **table**
name.

Maybe the table name is **Vocabwords**, please check again.